# how can find list of secrets and certificate list from Azure vault via golang?

Tags: azure, go, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

I'm trying to integrate azure vault using Golang. I used below code for getting key lists:

```
func (rcv Resources) KeyList(cred Credentials, subscriptionID, resourceGp, vaultName string) ([]string, error) {
    var (
        res []string
        err error
    )
    logger.Info("create client for connecting to the azure as vault client for getting key list.")
    cli := keyvault.NewKeysClient(subscriptionID)

    if cli.Authorizer, err = azureAD.Authorizer(cred.TenantID, cred.ClientID, cred.ClientSecret); err != nil {
        logger.Error("can not get authorizer for resources, err : ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    keyList, err := cli.List(context.Background(), resourceGp, "key-vault-zap-auth-scan2")
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("can not get resources list , error : ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    for _, key := range keyList.Values() {

        res = append(res, *key.Name)
    }
    return res, nil
}
```

As you know, we have different objects to store in azure key-vault such as: keys, secrets and certificates

I'm not able to get secrets list  with SDK, because it does not have secret client.

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For secrets, there's a separate package called [`azure-keyvault-secrets`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/keyvault/azsecrets@v0.1.1#section-readme).

To list secrets, the method you would want to call is `ListSecrets`. Here's an example for the same taken from [`here`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/keyvault/azsecrets@v0.1.1#readme-list-secrets):

```
cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
client, err := azsecrets.NewClient("https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/", cred, nil)

pager := client.ListSecrets(nil)
for pager.NextPage(context.Background()) {
    resp := pager.PageResponse()
    for _, secret := range resp.Secrets {
        fmt.Printf("Secret ID: %s", *secret.ID)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Gaurav works perfectly fine.. but only if you use package up to version `v0.5.0`.
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/keyvault/azsecrets?tab=versions

Starting from version `v0.6.0`, method `pager.NextPage()` returns 2 values `(ListSecretsPageResponse, error)` hence can not be used in `for` loop  -- you'd hit an error that looks something like `The non-bool value 'pager.NextPage(context.TODO())' (type (ListSecretsPageResponse, error)) used as a condition`.

Instead, you should use method `pager.More()` to loop through the pages of secrets.

Something along these lines:

```
    pager := client.ListSecrets(nil)
    for pager.More() {
        page, err := pager.NextPage(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        for _, v := range page.Secrets {
            fmt.Printf("Secret Name: %s\n", *v.ID)
        }
    }
```

hope this helps. cheers